# Impossible to launch graphic executables in nautilus

Tags: 64-bit, executable, mime-type

I recently re-installed Ubuntu in 64 bit, (before I had it in 32 bit).
I had the home folder on a partition and the system on another.
So when I re-installed I kept my old home folder.
My problem is that now, when I try to run my c++ executables that use the SDL, Nautilus tells me:

```
Could not display "program"

There is no application installed for "shared library" files.
Do you want to search for an application to open this file?
```

So the problem seems to be that nautilus thinks that it's a "shared library", but I have no idea about how to fix it!

How do I make it recognize as a normal executable file?

`file program` return :

```
program: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=39330e8ffbc9d3c5392da418d7fabecbb32334eb, stripped
```

and `mimetype program` return :

```
program: application/x-sharedlib
```

Comment: Could you please try to run the exectuable(s) in a terminal and [edit] your question to include its/their output? What's the output of `file /path/to/exe`? Thanks.

Comment: In fact, if I run the program in a terminal it works, but I can't launch it from nautilus

Comment: Could you please include the output of `file <EXE>` and `mimetype <EXE>` then?

Comment: So the problem seems to be more global and not only related to nautilus. I removed the nautilus tag.

Comment: The problem seems to be that g++ marks the file as a "position independent executable" and that when mimetype see that, it thinks that it's a shared library. So no solution seem possible, but I wonder why not everybody has this problem, 'cause I don't think that everybody use position dependent executables !

Comment: Yes, I found a few bug reports related to that but no real solution. What you can do as a workaround is to create a file type association for `application/x-sharedlibrary` that runs them as an executable. That should at least enable you to right-click and select "open with…".

Comment: I tried to do that before asking this question, but in nautilus I can only associate an "application" to a type of file. I noticed an application called "Run Software" but when I open my executables with that, nothing happens. How should I associate this type of file  to the action of running it ?

Comment: I would have tried to do it the same way.

Comment: You can see a better solution, using a Desktop launcher. <br>
https://askubuntu.com/questions/872683/cant-run-shared-library-in-nautilus/1206445#1206445

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be long-running bug:

https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=737849

I, too, would like to see it sorted out.

Regards

Peter

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think Nautilus team  will sort it out soon The problem is between Nautilus and file/libmagic project. file/libmagic cannot distinguish  between shared objects and executables in a reliable way.  So, when I sometimes need to execute binaries from Nautilus, I either drag it into a terminal window or create a one-word script. However, when I need to execute binaries more frequently, I switch to another file managers: Dolphin or Nemo. Dolphin, as I understand, is just executing any file with "execute" permission. Nemo asks in case of shared object: "Make executable and run" or "Choose a program".

Answer (score 0):

I created a script "RunFromThunar.sh"

```
#!/bin/bash
exec $1
```

... and in Thunar I associated "shared library" with this script. It works!
It must work in Nautilus the same way.

Answer (score 0):

I updated Ubuntu to 19.10. There are no changes to this problem. Nautilus still refuses to run 64-bit executable. Even after file/libmagic was fixed. Now the compiled executable is reported as "ELF 64-bit LSB pie executable" and not as before "ELF 64-bit LSB shared object". However, the Nautilus team did not change their approach, and I do not understand their reasons. If they want to protect users from accidentally clicking on a malware file, then a simple pop-up warning will be enough. (See the MS Windows warning when starting unsigned programs.) But, If they really want to completely ban the launch of malware, then this is simply impossible. There are many ways to trick inexperienced users.
What is worse for me is that Nemo (version 4.0.6) stopped offering "Make executable and run". (I mostly used Nemo before 19.10.) Either Nemo team shares Nautilus security fears, or they just copied part of the code from Nautilus. Dolphin does not lose the common sense. But, I am not ready to completely switch to Dolphin in GNOME environment.
I would like to mention once again when I need to run binaries from the file manager. I don't need it, when I install downloaded programs. Then a desktop launcher is the most appropriate option. But, when I am developing or researching, I can keep different versions of the complied executable file of the same program. Then I need to run the binary files from the file manager.
It seems that Nautilus team will not change their approach. Finally, I found a best solution for me. I created a desktop launcher that gets the file name and passes it as a command to the shell. Example below:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Run Executable
Comment=Run Executable
Exec="/bin/sh" -c %f
Icon=application.png
Terminal=false
```

I saved this launcher in ~/.local/share/applications as RunExecutable. So, I can select this launcher in "All Applications" list from "Open With" menu. This made my life as comfortable as before. Thus, I solver this problem in Nautilus & latest Nemo. However, I did not resolve my disagreement with the Nautilus teams. Nautilus should run executables in a straightforward way.