# Can't run "shared library" in nautilus

Tags: nautilus, 64-bit, executable, shared-library, mime-type

I recently re-installed Ubuntu in 64 bit, (before I had it in 32 bit). I had the home folder on a partition and the system on another. So when I re-installed I kept my old home folder.

My problem is that now, my c++ executables that use the SDL are recognize as "shared library", and so I can't directly run them from nautilus.
I searched for a solution, and found that it was caused by a bug of mime-type (see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gcc-defaults/+bug/1639531), which consider each file marked as "position independent executable" (by gcc) as a "shared library".

As It seems that there's no way to make mime-type recognize it normally, I would like to be able to launch "shared libraries" files in nautilus (as they are runnable from a terminal).
I tried to set the default program for this kind of file to an application called "Run Software" but when I try to launch it, nothing happens.

What is the right way to make nautilus to run a certain type of file and not to associate it with an application ?

Comment: for nautilus run the executable thru a .desktop file you create per executable & place the .desktop in an applications folder like /usr/share/applications or ~/.local/share/applications or /usr/local/share/applications

Comment: The fact is that I got a lot of files and it would be really boring to create a .desktop file for each

Comment: You said you "found that it was caused by a bug of mime-type..." Please [edit] your question to add a link to the bug report or other page you found where that is discussed. Also, you mentioned that writing .desktop files (as @doug suggested) would be too laborious to use as a workaround, if done manually. How about writing a script to generate them all? If that *might* be an acceptable solution, then I suggest [edit]ing your question to mention that and also include an example of a .desktop file for one of these programs that *does* work (or, if you cannot make one, describe the problem).

Comment: bug - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gcc-defaults/+bug/1639531

Comment: I tried to create a .desktop file, but it didn't worked :
`[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Program
Exec=/path/program` (the return characters are missing)
The thing is that my program uses images and .ttf files that are in his directory and so it don't work (I also tried `Exec=./program` but in this case it doesn't find the program ! )

Comment: look at here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45329372

Answer (score 2):

A better solution is to create a Desktop launcher, passing the full file name to the shell, like the below example.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Run Executable
Comment=Run Executable
Exec="/bin/sh" -c %f
Icon=application.png
Terminal=false
```

Save it under any name in  ~/.local/share/applications 
After this, open Nautilus, select the executable file, open the content menu by right-clicking and select the new launcher in "Open With Other Application' dialogue.
Thus, you can launch quickly any executable file.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. When I click on compiled executable in Nautilus (Files  3.20.4), I got the message:

> there is no application installed for "shared libraries" files"

There are two workarounds.

1. Just create a one line script in the same directory:

   ```
   ./my_program
   ```

   and set **Allow executing file as program** in Nautilus. (Or add `+x` via `chmod`.)
2. Open this directory in Terminal and run there. (or drag and drop the file from Nautilus to Terminal)

Comment: look at here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45329372