# I cannot run any executable from nautilus

Tags: 18.04, executable

With Ubuntu 18.04 have a problem. When compiling something, the executable binary is showed as shared-library in Nautilus.
When double clicked any executable file, I got the following message

"There is no application installed for "shared library" ......

Comment: However in terminal, I can run whatever I want.

Comment: No. Nautilus sees executable as shared library. When double-clicked, it says, "There is no application installed for "shared library" ...... "

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/929483/15811

Comment: -fno-pic -no-pie  is the solutlion. Thanx.

Comment: Hi John! Pease add an answer for your solution. Is it a Qt (qmake) specific problem?

Comment: You need  -no-pie in qmake command lines. If it doesn't work then we look for that.

Answer (score 3):

If you can't try non-extension of Ubuntu 18.04 - It looks like it doesn't work for the newest version. I think it works fine with *.sh because sometimes there's a copy violation of MacOS's shell or non-extension-able executable.

I have tried normal executable under Ubuntu 18.04, then you can replace yourapp with yourapp.sh then you can click yourapp.sh, then it will open the application.

PS: Please remember that for Ubuntu 18.04 need all replacement of yourapp"*" to yourapp".sh" - If system-engine-used binaries because it used by $PATH and any binaries like cp, rm etc don't need *.sh just let. If you are not sure for executable and shell format.

I hope you have tried to open executable and shell.