# Cannot open executable file (shared library)?

Tags: executable

I compiled some software from GitHub and I tried to run it, but I can't.

[image: Screenshot]

Any ideas why it is not working?

Comment: The repo would tell you better or the readme file!

Comment: It would help a lot if you told what and how you did to build your software. Maybe try to run it from terminal to get the full error text.

Comment: See [Impossible to launch graphic executables in nautilus](https://askubuntu.com/questions/871926/impossible-to-launch-graphic-executables-in-nautilus)

Answer (score 0):

Compiling from `github` source code is more complicated than simple installation. Your package is available for Ubuntu 14.04 and 16.04 according to the vendor. To see if it is available for a different Ubuntu version use this command:

```
$ apt search aseprite

Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done
aseprite/xenial 1.0.9+ds-3.2 amd64
  sprite and pixel art editor
```

To do a "dry-run" installation (simulated installation) use this command:

```
$ sudo apt install -s aseprite

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  liballegro4.4 libloadpng4.4 libtinyxml2.6.2v5
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  aseprite liballegro4.4 libloadpng4.4 libtinyxml2.6.2v5
0 upgraded, 4 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Inst liballegro4.4 (2:4.4.2-7 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [amd64])
Inst libloadpng4.4 (2:4.4.2-7 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [amd64])
Inst libtinyxml2.6.2v5 (2.6.2-3 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [amd64])
Inst aseprite (1.0.9+ds-3.2 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [amd64])
Conf liballegro4.4 (2:4.4.2-7 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [amd64])
Conf libloadpng4.4 (2:4.4.2-7 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [amd64])
Conf libtinyxml2.6.2v5 (2.6.2-3 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [amd64])
Conf aseprite (1.0.9+ds-3.2 Ubuntu:16.04/xenial [amd64])
```

As you can see the `aseprite` application is dependent on many other libraries that need to be installed. I suspect when you compile manually some of these libraries are missing.

To do a real installation use:

```
sudo apt install aseprite
```